# Django _set error: "'Campaign' object has no attribute 'charity_set'"

Tags: python, django

I have a model Charity with a ManyToManyField relation to Campaign, as seen below:

```
class Charity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    tag_line = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True,null=True)
    campaigns = models.ManyToManyField(Campaign, related_name='campaign_charity')
    ...
```

The ManyToManyField works fine, and campaigns.all() returns the correct set of campaigns associated with a charity. When I try to get the reverse set of an object using object.charity_set I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Campaign' object has no attribute 'charity_set'
```

Any idea why? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the `related_name` attribute overides the default `model_set` attribute.

I would try:

```
object.campaign_charity.all()
```

if you ever want to see all attributes/methods of an object run `dir(object)`